# Why the extensions are visible on frontend after disabling from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, extensions, frontend

I am building the website called [cravestore.in](http://www.cravestore.in). I have disabled the pin code extension from admin panel but still it is visible on front page. I have installed this extension manually through FileZilla FTP client. How to remove this extension from frontend which is disabled in admin panel. I have cleared all the index & cache & flushed magento cache as well, but no success.
Attached are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/etc/modules and delete the XML file of that specific extension. That’s the correct way to disable it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/182811)

Comment: He asked how to disable it. I provided a direct-to-the-point answer of how to disable it.